# What is a 5 letter word that you can remove the first or second letter and all 3 words sound the same

Tags: word

What is a 5 letter word that you can remove the first or second letter and all 3 words sound the same?

I don’t know the answer so I don’t have any information other than the question.

Comment: Where did you find this puzzle?

Comment: Shouldn't be closed for lacking proper attribution. It is too dinky.

Answer (score 6):

One example is the word

> *scent*.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is

> **llama** – beast
>
>  The other two words are the same word:
>  **lama** – priest
>
>  and their meanings rhyme too!